# Real solution of $\cos(\sin(x)) = x$ is a transcendental number?

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

If $x \in \mathbb R$ then the solution for the equation $$\cos(\sin(x)) = x$$ is a transcendental number or not?

I'm trying to use Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem and Euler's formula for the proof of this (by contradiction), but I'm stucked on this part: $$e^{i\sin(x)}=x + i\sqrt{1 - x^2}$$
if we assume $x \in \mathbb A$ then $i\sin(x)=t \notin \mathbb A$, but $e^t$ is a algebraic number or it is not? And if $x \notin \mathbb A$ then what is $i\sin(x)$?

Comment: Dottie number, solution of $x=\cos(x)$ is already  transcendental . I fully agree that this is not a proof.

Comment: Just for the fun of it, I passed the number to one of my friend. He came with the approximation $$\Bigg[e^{-37-\frac{15}{e}-19 e+\frac{22}{\pi }+4 \pi } \pi ^{35 e-22} \sin ^{25}(e \pi )
   \cos ^{10}(e \pi )\Bigg]^{1/7}$$ which gives an error of $2.21\times 10^{-19}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici that approximation looks cool.

Comment: This is first cousin to the question of whether e.g. $\pi^{\pi^{\pi^\pi}}$ (or iterated further if you prefer) is an integer; almost certainly not, but AFAIK proofs have been hard to come by.

Comment: If Lindemann-Weierstrass does not solve this problem, then there is probably no way. I even doubt that the irrationality can be easily proven in this case.